# dynamic fields generation based on form input field value

Tags: javascript

In html form i have a field as number of subjects. My question is if i given the value as 4, then four text fields needs to be created. With each row taking the input field value for subject name and marks.
Please help me how to write java code to generate the fields dynamically based on input value.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned Java but tagged the question JavaScript. So I am assuming you mean JavaScript.

That said, you can manipulate HTML in accordance with the DOM(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) and use the .appendChild(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) method to insert the new text fields.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Enter number of subjects:</h1>

        <input type="number" id="inputValue">

        <button type="button" id="submitInput">Submit</button>

        <br>
        <br>

        <form id="form">


        </form>

        <script src="test.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
const numberOfInputs = document.getElementById('submitInput');

numberOfInputs.onclick = function() {

    const inputValue = document.getElementById("inputValue").value;

    for (let i = 0; i < inputValue; i++) {

        document.getElementById("form").appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
    }
}
```